# Background image is not loading

Tags: css

Image is not displaying in my page.

```
<div class="rating" style="width:25%;float:right;height:100px">
       <span class="truckIcon">
       <!-- <img src="../images/logo/favicon.png">
       </span> -->
</div>
```

css:

```
.truckIcon{
    background-image: url(../images/icons/favicon.png);no-repeat !important;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
}
```

This is my css path: `\ulmt\html\css\style.css`
This is my image path: `\ulmt\html\images\icons\favicon.png`

Is anything wrong here?

Comment: It should read background: url('...') no-repeat !important or add background-repeat: no-repeat !important after your background-image

Comment: <span class="truckIcon"> is an inline element . either block level element or inline-block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have used span element which is an inline element. so your width and height will not be applied on it. To make it work add a property called display:inline-block;

```
.truckIcon{background-image: url(../images/icons/favicon.png)no-repeat !important;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @JoostS can i have a look around of your work which you did ?

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to say

Answer (score 3):

`.truckIcon` is line-element so that you need to add `display:inline-block` for that and one more thing `background-image` not work with `no-repeat` so that you need to add `background-repeat: no-repeat !important;`

```
.truckIcon{
    background-image: url(../images/icons/favicon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

background-image not support no-repeat so try with this:

```
 .truckIcon{
    background: url(../images/icons/favicon.png) no-repeat !important;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just remove the semicolon before no-repeat. The style should be

```css
.truckIcon{background-image: url(../images/icons/favicon.png)no-repeat !important;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove semicolon **`;`** just before `no-repeat` from the image url in your CSS, like:

```
.truckIcon {
  background-image: url(../images/icons/favicon.png) no-repeat !important;
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

span is a inline element. so you need to style display: block; or display:inline-block;
also uncomment your close span tag after img tag

```
.truckIcon{
    background-image: url(../images/icons/favicon.png)no-repeat !important;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just simply change this CSS it would defiantly work.

```css
.truckIcon{background-image: url(../images/icons/favicon.png) no-repeat !important;
width:80px;
height:80px;
display:inlin-block;
}
```